# How can I replace the last occurrence of a String with another String?

Tags: haskell

I am looking for a function of type `String (what to replace) -> String (what to replace it with) -> String (the string) -> String (the result)`. It should only replace the last occurrence. I would accept a solution that uses `Text` instead of `String`. I searched hoogle and stackage and did not find a function.

Comment: We actually don't have one of those in the standard library.  Weird, huh?  First thing that comes to mind is using a [regex package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.1/docs/Text-Regex.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one in the standard library.  It's not hard to write though (however it's not the most efficient implementation).  Because of the structure of lists, it's actually much more convenient to replace the first one.

```
import Data.List (stripPrefix)

replace :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replace needle newNeedle [] = []
replace needle newNeedle (h:haystack) =
    case stripPrefix needle (h:haystack) of
        Just haystack' -> newNeedle ++ haystack'
        Nothing -> h : replace needle newNeedle haystack
```

Then to get the last one you can do some reversal gymnastics.

```
replaceLast :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
replaceLast needle newNeedle haystack
    = reverse $ replace (reverse needle) (reverse newNeedle) (reverse haystack)
```

Comment: Hey answer accepter -- this code has bugs!  Still working on it :-P

Comment: ok it's better now